# DocBook with WebHelp - can you specify a page anchor at the root of the HTML page and find it deep in the document?

Tags: html, docbook

I am using WebHelp to render my DocBook document.

Within my DocBook file, if I have an anchor as follows:

```
<anchor id="thisIsSomeExample" />
```

I am able to reach it within my WebHelp render using a URL such as:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyWebHelpProject/book/pages/ch01s01.html#thisIsSomeExample
```

This is great, but what I really want to be able to do is find that anchor, irrespective of what section of whatever chapter is currently open on my screen:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyWebHelpProject/book/pages/#thisIsSomeExample
```

Is this possible?

**Edit:** Following the sound suggestion of `@Sitapati Das` to render the entire document in one page I must add that we require to split the document up by chapter. The document is very large (over 300 pages when printed in A4).

Comment: What do you mean by 'my WebHelp render'? A web browser? Then probably not, or you would need to search for a smart plugin (or build one) that can search through multiple documents (=files).

Comment: The WebHelp war file produced by the DocBkX plugin. http://wiki.docbook.org/WebHelp. I ask the question as I anticipate that this is a common requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be possible if you render your help file as html-single, and use unique anchor IDs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However it is a requirement for us to break up the document by chapter (so one XML DocBook document per chapter), as the document is very large (over 300 pages when printed in A4)

Comment: I have accepted this answer because I now understand that this is the only way to achieve a global unique anchor ID within DocBook. It is not possible to specify one at a high level and it to apply to all child pages.